# Can I create multiple onclick events dynamically?

Tags: javascript

For some reason I am unable to re-enable a button and go through all of the columns I have in a table with the same button. Can I create multiple onclick events for the button? The HTML itself is really just a button within a table.

```
   function focaccia(x){
     var table = document.getElementById("orderTable");
      var row = table.insertRow(0);

      var rem = document.createElement("button");
      var name = document.createTextNode("Remove");
      rem.appendChild(name);

      rem.onclick = function(){
        x.disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("orderTable").deleteRow(this);
        var table = document.getElementById("orderTable");
        var amount = 0;
        var tot;
        for(var x = 0; x < table.rows.length; x++){
         amount = amount + parseInt(table.rows[x].cells[1].children[0].value);
        }
        tot = amount * 9;
        document.getTotal.total.value = tot;
      }

      var num = document.createElement("input");
      num.size = 2;

      num.onchange = function(){

        var table = document.getElementById("orderTable");
        var amount = 0;
        var tot;
        for(var x = 0; x < table.rows.length; x++){
         amount = amount + parseInt(table.rows[x].cells[1].children[0].value);
        }
        tot = amount * 9;
        document.getTotal.total.value = tot;
      }

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

        cell1.innerHTML = "Focaccia";
        cell2.appendChild(num);
        cell3.appendChild(rem);
        x.disabled = true;
        num.value = 1;
        total = total + 9;
        document.getTotal.total.value = total;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `addEventListener`.

Instead of `target.onclick=clickHandlerFunction;`, use target.addEventListener('click', clickHandlerFunction);'

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener

Note: The syntax for adding events using old Internet Explorer is different (`target.attachEvent('onclick',handler)`). If you need compatibility with old browsers, you can use both syntaxes, use jQuery's [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) or [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) functions or [gator.js](http://craig.is/riding/gators).

Comment: such as `rem.addEventListener("click", function(){/////code here/////});`

Comment: @PuddingCat that's correct, but if you want to remove the listener ([`target.removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener)) later you would need to use a named function.