# Combining multiple onClick events

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am very new to Javascript and I am struggling with a certain task I am trying to do. I came across these two in my search but don't relate to my issues.

[Multiple onclick events in Javascript/html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41104323/multiple-onclick-events-in-javascript-html)

[Can I create multiple onclick events dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27977088/can-i-create-multiple-onclick-events-dynamically)

So this is what I have. I have icons which if you click on them perform a certain onClick event. I am trying to combine them so you if you toggle them the icons change which I have accomplished the toggling of the icons like so.

```
 onClick="$(this).find('i').attr('class', ($(this).attr('aria-expanded') == 'false' ? 'fa fa-times-circle-o' : 'fa fa-play-circle-o'));"
```

Now here is where I am stuck and my research has come up empty. I need to add the onClick functions to icons and I am not sure how to accomplish this.

So when fa fa-play-circle-o is clicked it will trigger triggerRadarAnimation(); and the icon will toggle to the fa fa-times-circle-o and when that icon is pressed it will trigger radarAnimateKill(); and toggle back to the other icon.

I have the toggle functionality working, just not sure how to add those functions above to the toggle feature. Any guidance on where I can find a solution to this?

Comment: Can you provide some more code as your question is a ambiguous and try to add a js function instead of writing js in the element

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery you can try something like this:

```
 // Bind a click handler that can perform logic in its handler
 $(selectorString).click(function(event){
   // Toggle both classes, so we get the right state
   $(this)
     .find('i')
     .toggleClass('fa-play-circle-o')
     .toggleClass('fa-times-circle-o');

   // Check which class is currently applied, and run the appropriate 
   // animation.
   if($($(this).find('i')).hasClass('fa-times-circle-o')) {
     triggerRadarAnimation();
   } else {
     radarAnimateKill();
   }
 })
```